# Rails not including timestamps even though I specifically ask for them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently having a problem with RoR. I need the fields created_at and updated_at in in my tables for further use. However rails doesn't seem to add them even though I ask rails to. These are my models:

```
Picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
    validates_presence_of :photo
end    

Category.rb    
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end    

Comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :picture

  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

These are my migrations:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.references :category, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :pictures, :categories
  end
end

class AddPhotoToPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pictures, :photo, :string
  end
end


class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :text
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :picture, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :comments, :users
    add_foreign_key :comments, :pictures
  end
end

class AddTimeStampsToPicture < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change_table
    change_table :pictures do |t|
    t.timestamps
    end
end
```

As you can see I am trying to add the 2 columns. When I try seeing the created_at field it will say `"undefined method created_at'"` . I am checking in `rails c` to see if the fields are there but no, the fields do not exist. I am using PG gem . Also I am using carrierwave gem to upload the pictures. Why would rails not include these 2 columns ? Here is a  [link](https://github.com/Skillvendor/PhotoProject)  to the project itself.
As coorasse suggested I took a look at the schema.

```
create_table "pictures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "photo_file_name"
    t.string   "photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
    t.string   "photo"
  end
```

It seems it didn't update herself. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force shema to be updated you would drop the db and recreate it.

But be aware - it will erase whole database.

```
rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate
```

You can't just edit the schema or migration files. If you are adding new columns - you should do it through new migration.

But if you are taking the editing migrations files road you'll have (problems) to drop the DB and recreate it.

Comment: thought that's what db:reset does . Let me try :D

Comment: It worked :P. Well at first I tried to just add them with the migration AddTimeStampsToPicture. It didn't work. That's when I edited them and called db:reset (I thought it resets schema also honestly, but it does not) . This is the answer :P simple enough. Thank you

Comment: No probs, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Check if you ran the migrations with `rake db:migrate` then double check your `schema.rb` file.

You have to run the migrations for your changes to take effect

Comment: yes I ran the migrations , and I also did rake db:reset several times

Comment: seems the schema didn't update herself... How do I force her to do that ?